# Windows Store App binding of CheckBox does not work (occassionally)

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I have the following piece of XAML:

```
<GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Background="#286C9A" Width="336" Height="22">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Checked}" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
```

It's a template in a ListView. Checked is a bool property, and the problem is that the initial value of the property is transferred correctly to the view (both TextBlock and CheckBox). But following changes to the property is only reflected on the TextBlock, the Checkbox does not react.

Can someone tell me what happens?

EDIT:

The relevant part (I believe) of the ViewModel is this :

```
public class MenuGroup : ObservableCollection<MenuItem>
{
    bool @checked;

    public bool Checked
    {
        get { return @checked; }
        set
        {
            if (@checked == value) return;
            @checked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Checked"));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: It is apparent that the binding stops working the first time I have clicked on the checkbox and thus manually changed it's state. And it works all the way if it's TwoWay binding. But why that is, I don't know.**

Comment: show your properties definition in behind-code

Comment: @letiagoalves I'm using Caliburn so it's not exactly in code behind, but I'll edit it in now.

Comment: @letiagoalves done :)  I have a few other unrelated props in there, I omitted those.